# Retrieving specific GroupId based on UserId's

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is a scenario where we wanna retrieve the specific GroupId no. Eg., 6 having only 3 users say UserId's with 2, 1, 3 with that specific Group

This is the query I tried to execute

```
SELECT group_id FROM group_users WHERE group_id IN(SELECT group_id FROM group_users GROUP BY group_id HAVING COUNT(*)=3) AND userid IN (1, 2, 3);
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/807ea1e/2/0)

**Below are the details from the above query which had been broken into pieces**

```
SELECT group_id FROM group_users GROUP BY group_id HAVING COUNT(*)=3

group_id
5
6
```

---

```
SELECT group_id FROM group_users WHERE group_id IN(SELECT group_id FROM group_users GROUP BY group_id HAVING COUNT(*)=3)

group_id
5
5
5
6
6
6
```

---

```
SELECT group_id FROM group_users WHERE group_id IN(SELECT group_id FROM group_users GROUP BY group_id HAVING COUNT(*)=3) AND userid IN (1, 2, 3)

group_id
5
5
6
6
6
```

---

```
SELECT group_id FROM group_users WHERE group_id IN(SELECT group_id FROM group_users GROUP BY group_id HAVING COUNT(*)=3) AND userid=1 AND userid=2 and userid = 3

group_id
NULL
```

---

### Expected Result:

```
group_id
6
```

**Since there is only one group with `group_id = 6` having 3 users with unique `userid = 1, 2, 3`**

**So that `group_id = 6` must be retrieved at the end result!**

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional counting in the `HAVING` clause. In MySQL, you can simply sum up met conditions, because true = 1 and false = 0 in MySQL.

```
SELECT group_id
FROM group_users 
GROUP BY group_id 
HAVING SUM(userid IN (1, 2, 3)) = 3
   AND SUM(userid NOT IN (1, 2, 3)) = 0;
```

Another, even simpler option is to concat the user IDs and check the string:

```
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(userid ORDER BY userid) = '1,2,3';
```

Answer (score 1):

So, you are right. You have to intersect groups with exactly 3 users with groups that contain the minimum of 3 users (1,2,3).

### Maria DB 10.2 onwards,

```
SELECT group_id FROM group_users 
GROUP BY group_id 
HAVING COUNT(*)=3
INTERSECT
SELECT group_id FROM group_users 
WHERE userid IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY group_id 
HAVING COUNT(*)=3
```

[Click Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=3c7880eeeef7a330debddbb46b5d8237)

### For MySQL 5.6,

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.group_id FROM
(SELECT group_id FROM group_users 
GROUP BY group_id 
HAVING COUNT(*)=3) a,
(SELECT group_id FROM group_users 
WHERE userid IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY group_id 
HAVING COUNT(*)=3) b
WHERE a.group_id=b.group_id
```

[Click Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/807ea1e/9)

Comment: You could try this: SELECT group_id FROM group_users WHERE userid IN (1, 2, 3) GROUP BY group_id HAVING COUNT(*)=3;

Comment: Have you tried it in MySQL [click](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/807ea1e/6)

Comment: 1 errors were found during analysis.

This type of clause was previously parsed. (near "SELECT" at position 85)   #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTERSECT
SELECT group_id FROM group_users 
WHERE userid IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP B' at line 4

Comment: Sory, pure sql. In Mysql you could simulate only intersect. http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-intersect/. I can't insert sql in comment because i write on phone and ENTER send the comment, it not inserting new line.

Comment: So check here with this link http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/807ea1e/6 and let me know if the resulted answer should be `group_id=6` paste the link I will check it out

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT group_id FROM
(SELECT group_id FROM group_users 
GROUP BY group_id 
HAVING COUNT(*)=3) a,
(SELECT group_id FROM group_users 
WHERE userid IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY group_id 
HAVING COUNT(*)=3) b
WHERE a.group_id=b.group_id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186220/discussion-between-virgil-ionescu-and-nishanth-).